# Python try except not working when adding for loop after

Tags: sql, python-3.x, for-loop, try-except

Not sure what the issue is with this, as I am using the same code in several places but is only breaking in one place. Connecting to sql db to append values to a list. Python 3.x

```
powder = []
try:
    cnxn = p.connect('DRIVER={/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.5.so.2.1};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+db+';UID='+un+';PWD='+pw)
    cursor = cnxn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Something='THING'")
    powd = cursor.fetchall()
except:
    powd = [['DUCKS']]

for p in powd:
     powder.append(p[0])
```

If the for loop is left off, it runs perfectly, the try succeeds and powd has all my needed values. When I add the for loop the try fails every time (first line doesn't even run).
I tried moving the for loop into the try and also tried adding a finally after except.
I am running this same code for different SQL Statements (most of which are more complex/larger datasets) and this code works perfect. Not sure what could be causing it to fail in this or how to get around it. Any thoughts/suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: could you provide the error message?

Comment: there is no actual error message, it just goes runs the except condition instead of the try

Comment: if you catch the error:
`except Exception as e:
   print(e)`

Comment: ```local variable 'p' referenced before assignment```

Comment: So `p.connect` - where do you declare p?

Comment: use `import pyodbc as p` but you shoukld choose your variable names better

Comment: @nbk i thought that ! but i asked because i can't reproduce the error :P

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out

```
import pyodbc as p
```

for loop was using p as the variable, once I changed that to pn it worked like a charm. Was trying to use a variable I already had set. Opps.

```
for pn in powd:
     powder.append(pn[0])
```